# MySQL Stored procedure "DECLARE is not a valid"

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to made a stored procdure, to add 1 to an assignments downloads and subtract 1 from a Users credit.

My best guess:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Library`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `download`(
        IN p_assignmentId INT(11),
        IN p_userId INT(11)
    )
BEGIN
    DECLARE p_credit INT unsigned DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE p_downloads INT unsigned DEFAULT 1;

SELECT credit
INTO p_credit 
FROM Users
WHERE userId = p_userId;

SELECT downloads
INTO p_downloads
FROM Assignments
WHERE assignmentId = p_assignmentId;


    UPDATE Users
    SET credit = p_credit - 1 
    WHERE userId = p_userId;

    UPDATE Assignments
    SET downloads = p_downloads +1
    WHERE assignmentId = p_assignmentId;


END
```

Its complaining about my declare statements needing a semicolon, which does not seem to be the case, so any guesses?

Comment: Are you preceding the CREATE with a DELIMITER change? `DELIMITER $$ CREATE ... BEGIN ... END$$  DELIMITER ;` is the common method.

Comment: I just edited for clariy, this is all i have.

Comment: Ok it worked when i did it by clicking "Create new procedure" instead of doing it in a query.

Comment: If you are using MySQL Workbench, you can right click the stored procedure in the tree view to see the full create (with delimiter changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Stored Procedures and Functions often need DELIMITER overrides to prevent their own body statements from prematurely terminating their CREATE statement; this is conventionally accomplished with this kind of template:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE ...
BEGIN 
   [stmt];
   [stmt2];
   ....
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```